# Kiosk Mode Android wear

Tags: android, adb, wear-os, sony-smartwatch

I'm trying to make kiosk mode in smart watch.
I'm having now two big problems in an attempt to implement Device Administration :

1. The following uses-feature are undefined:
        android.software.managed_users
        android.software.device_admin
2. The flag "ro.config.low_ram" is set , I try to make it undefined .

[According to 
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/implement.html]

In addition , 
I will be happy, if you have a better idea to make kiosk mode in smart watch .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I keep the screen on with:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Then I disabled the left swipe by creating a new style.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

res/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now the only way to close the app is through the button. Maybe there is a way to override this but worst case there is always super-glue.

Comment: Use can also use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` to keep it running in the background if another notification etc closes the app.

Comment: @mike I had it inside onCreate()