# How to enforce a Kiosk Mode for Google Wear OS, to run a single application?

Tags: wear-os

For [Google Wear OS](https://wearos.google.com/), how can it be locked down to run a single application, commonly known as `kiosk mode` in Android?

I've seen similar questions but they relate to the older `Android Wear`, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718301/kiosk-mode-android-wear).

This is a typical use of watches based on `FreeRTOS`

Example use case:
Company who wants to create a watch for workers, who can only access a single custom application.